# Не появляется изображение

Tags: javascript, html, css

В слайдере внутрь кнопки решил засунуть изображение, но оно не отображается так как пишет не может найти. Уже несколько раз перепроверял путь к изображению, изображение находит, но оно по-прежнему не отображается. Пробовал по разному прописывать путь к изображению, не помогает
../image/categorizes__slick.svg; /main/image/categorizes__slick.svg

```js
$(function(){
    $('.categorizes__slider').slick({
        dots:false,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="categorizes__slick-prev">' +
            '<img src="../image/categorizes__slick.svg" alt="button-prev">' +
            '</button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="categorizes__slick-next">' +
            '<img src="/main/image/categorizes__slick.svg" alt="button-next">' +
            '</button>',
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1440,
                settings: {
                    dots:false,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite: true,
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    arrows: true,

                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь к изображению

Comment: Тоже пробовал не помогло

Comment: Посмотрите еще вкладку network. Может там что блокируется? И проверьте, что имена правильные. + попробуйте такие варианты `./main` `main`